# Why does Ruby require .call for Proc invocation?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I just wondered whether there is any good reason for or even an advantage in having to invoke `Proc`s using `proc.call(args)` in Ruby, which makes higher-order function syntax much more verbose and less intuitive.

Why not just `proc(args)`? Why draw a distinction between functions, lambdas and blocks? Basically, it's all the same thing so why this confusing syntax? Or is there any point for it I don't realize?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *need* some way to distinguish between *calling* the `Proc` and *passing* it around.

In Python and ECMAScript, it's simple: with parentheses it's a call, without it's not. In Ruby, leaving off the parentheses is *also* a call, therefore, there must be some *other* way to distinguish.

In Ruby 1.8, `Proc#call` and its alias `Proc#[]` serve that distinction. As of Ruby 1.9, `obj.(arg)` is syntactic sugar for `obj.call(arg)` and `Proc#()` is *also* an alias for `Proc#call`.

So, you can call a `Proc` like this:

- foo.call(1, 2, 3)
- foo[1, 2, 3]
- foo.(1, 2, 3)

And you can even also define `()` for your *own* classes.

BTW: the same problem is also why you have to use the `method` method to get a hold of a method object.

Answer (score 6):

In ruby you can have a local variable and a method that are both named foo. Assuming the method is private, the only way to call it would be `foo(args)` (`self.foo(args)` would not work for private methods which can't have an explicit receiver). If ruby would allow to overload the () operator, so that the foo in `foo(bar)` can be a variable, there would be no way to call the private method foo, when there is also a local variable named foo.

Note that with features like `define_method` and `method_missing`, it is not always possible to avoid situations where you have methods and local variables of the same name.

Comment: To split hairs, there's one private method that ruby allows an explicit receiver for: self.foo=(args) , to distinguish between creating a local variable and calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be able to pass it around *without* calling it, right? Requiring that it be explicitly called allows that. Otherwise, every time you tried to use the proc as a parameter, you would end up calling it.

Comment: To expand: In Ruby, parentheses for method calls are optional, so the interpreter can't tell the difference between `proc`, or just passing the closure around, and `proc` as a synonym for `proc()`.